# How to hide post published date?

Tags: date

How to hide published date programmatically from all posts?

I've tried adding filters, hiding some post metadata, but as I'm new to WordPress didn't figured it out yet.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Website URL / Theme?

Comment: Theme is called smart-mag and there is child theme in the repo, however i cannot share the url

Comment: Options: determine which template and/or partial is responsible for it and modify there with conditional PHP or removal.  Find a combination of CSS selectors and hide it with a style rule.

Comment: Please read [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

Add `entry-date { display: none; }`  to the stylesheet. 
Better create a child theme and add the code to the newly created stylesheet, if you dont you may lose the code when you update your theme to a latest version.